# Should we avoid nested rxjs operators? One case which I cannot test

Tags: rxjs, rxjs-pipeable-operators, jasmine-marbles, rxjs-marbles, marble-diagram

I have written the following effect in my Angular app which uses `rxjs`. On `MyActions.myAction`, I receive an object containing a property `ids` - an array of ids - and for each id I want to send an HTTP request via `this.myApiService.getResource`, which returns an `Observable<Resource>`. I want then to collect all results in an array, and dispatch another action passing the array.

```
  public loadResources$: Observable<MyAction> = this.actions$.pipe(
    ofType(MyActions.myAction),
    switchMap(({ ids }) => from(ids).pipe(
      mergeMap(id => this.myApiService.getResource(id)),
      toArray()
    )),
    map(resources) => MyActions.resourcesLoaded({ resources } )),
  );
```

The code above does the job, but I wonder whether I should avoid nesting two flows of reactive operators, and whether there is a better way to write that.

The reason I wonder that is that I am having problems writing a test for it. I wrote the test below but I cannot make it pass.

```
 it('should dispatch an resourcesLoaded action with the resources', () => {
      const ids = ['5f7c723832758b859bd8f866'];
      const resources = [{} as Resource];

      const values = {
        l: MyActions.loadResources({ ids }),
        t: ids[0],
        o: MyActions.resourcesLoaded({ resources })
      };

      actions =         hot('--l------------', values);
      const get$ =     cold('  -------t-----', values);
      const expected = cold('---------o-----', values);

      myApiService.getResource.withArgs(ids[0]).returns(get$);

      expect(myEffects.loadResources$).toBeObservable(expected);
    });
```

The error I get is:

```
     Expected $.length = 0 to equal 1.
Expected $[0] = undefined to equal Object({ frame: 50, notification: Notification({ kind: 'N', value: { ....
Error: Expected $.length = 0 to equal 1.
Expected $[0] = undefined to equal Object({ frame: 50, notification: Notification({ kind: 'N', value: { ....
    at <Jasmine>
    at compare (http://localhost:9876/Users/jacopolanzoni/Documents/Development/myProject/node_modules/jasmine-marbles/index.js:91:1)
    at <Jasmine>
```

Comment: What's the error you're getting?

Comment: Expect $.length = 0 to equal 1. Apologies for missing this in the question, I will update it now. Btw, I think it may be toArray waiting for httpClient.get to complete.

Comment: No worries. 'toArray waiting for httpClient.get to complete' - aren't you mocking `myApiService.getResource`? I'm assuming that the real `myApiService.getResource` uses HttpClient.get(). But  you're right, `toArray` waits for the source to complete, which doesn't happen in your case, because `get$` never completes. Maybe if you change '-t-' into `-(t|)-` in the `get$` obs, will it work?

Comment: That's exactly what I did, and the test now passes. Thanks Andrei! Yet what do you think about the method itself? Do you see a better way to write it? I haven't seen many nested operators like that, so I was wondering whether that's good practice or not.

Comment: I'd say it depends on what you want to achieve, at least in this case. `of([1,2,3]).pipe(mergeAll(), switchMap(value => http.get(...)))` differs from `of([1,2,3]).pipe(switchMap(ids => from(ids).pipe(mergeMap(...))))`. In the former, each inner obs will be discarded by the next value, so only `3` will resolve. In the second scenario, it will process all of them, because you explode the array in the inner obs(which is _managed_ by swtichMap).

Comment: Yeah, I actually need the second options, so I think I am good as I am. If you can expand your last comment in an answer, I'd be happy to accept it as valid answer for my question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> but I wonder whether I should avoid nesting two flows of reactive operators, and whether there is a better way to write that

I'd say it depends on what you want to achieve, at least in this case.

```js
of([1,2,3]).pipe(mergeAll(), switchMap(value => http.get(...)))
```

differs from

```js
of([1,2,3]).pipe(switchMap(ids => from(ids).pipe(mergeMap(...))))
```

In the first scenario, each inner observable will be discarded by the next value(except for the last value), so only 3 will resolve.
In the second scenario, it will process all of them, because you explode the array in the inner observable(which is managed by `swtichMap`, so the only way its inner observable will be discarded is if a new outer value(e.g another array of ids) is emitted by the source).

A case where nesting is not necessary is:

```js
of([1,2,3])
  .pipe(
    // whenever you want to explode an array,
    // it does not matter which higher order operator you use
    // since the operation is **synchronous**
    // so, `mergeAll`, `concatAll`, `switchAll` should work the same
    mergeAll(),

    mergeAll(id => this.apiService.useId(id))
  )

// same as

of([1,2,3])
  .pipe(
    mergeMap(ids => from(ids).pipe(mergeMap(id => this.apiService.useId(id))))
  )
```

As you can see, in this case, `switchMap` has been replaced with `mergeMap`.

Answer (score 0):

I have found out my test was failing because `toArray` was waiting for the observable returned by `getResource` (i.e., `httpClient.get`) to complete. Replacing `t` with `(t|)` fixes the test:

```
 it('should dispatch an resourcesLoaded action with the resources', () => {
      const ids = ['5f7c723832758b859bd8f866'];
      const resources = [{} as Resource];

      const values = {
        l: MyActions.loadResources({ ids }),
        t: ids[0],
        o: MyActions.resourcesLoaded({ resources })
      };

      actions =         hot('--l------------', values);
      const get$ =     cold('  -------(t|)-----', values);
      const expected = cold('---------o-----', values);

      myApiService.getResource.withArgs(ids[0]).returns(get$);

      expect(myEffects.loadResources$).toBeObservable(expected);
    });
```

Yet, the first part of my question, i.e. whether it's good practice or not to nest operators like that, still stands.